# jQuery unwrap only if parent has class

Tags: jquery

Im using jQuery's unwrap function however I want it to only unwrap if the parent div (the one to be deleted) has a certain class.

I was using this:

```
$('.children').unwrap();
```

I tried changing it to this, so the parent would only be removed if it has a class of 'parent', but the code behaves the same as above. Thanks

```
$('.children').unwrap('.parent');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('.parent > .children').unwrap();
```

Try the above :)